# PHP/JS Contact Form - Validation

Tags: javascript, php, contact-form

I cannot get this form to work. Everything I do it just comes up with an error and also says that the phone number isn't valid but when I look at the code I can't really see why it isn't working.

P.S. I don't really have any understanding of PHP or JS so I don't really know what I'm looking for when it comes to errors.

Thank you for any help.

Here's the HTML

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="cform" name="cform">
          <ul id="homehireus" class="hireform contactform">
            <li>
              <label>Name:<span class="required">*</span></label>
              <input name="name" id="name" type="text" value="" tabindex="1">
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Phone:</label>
              <input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" value="" tabindex="2">
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Email:<span class="required">*</span></label>
              <input name="email" id="email" type="text" value="" tabindex="3">
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Subject:</label>
              <input name="subject" id="subject" type="text" value="" tabindex="4">
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Message:<span class="required">*</span></label>
              <textarea name="message" id="message" tabindex="5"></textarea>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="button" id="send-message" value="Send Details To iPhone Repairs" tabindex="6">
              <div id="output" class="contactpage-msg"></div>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </form>
```

PHP

```
 <?php 

$send_email_to = "naomi.deluca@me.com";

function send_email($name,$email,$phone,$subject,$message)
{
  global $send_email_to;  
  if($message=='message')$message='';
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: ".$email. "\r\n";
  $message = "<strong>Email = </strong>".$email."<br>";  
  $message .= "<strong>Name = </strong>".$name."<br>";     
  $message .= "<strong>Phone = </strong>".$phone."<br>";     
  $message .= "<strong>Message = </strong>".$message."<br>";
  @mail($send_email_to, $subject, $message,$headers);
  return true;
}

function validate($name,$email,$phone,$message,$subject)
{
  $return_array = array();
  $return_array['success'] = '1';
  $return_array['name_msg'] = '';  
  $return_array['email_msg'] = '';
  $return_array['phone_msg'] = '';
  $return_array['message_msg'] = '';
  $return_array['subject_msg'] = '';

 if($email == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['email_msg'] = 'email is required';
  }
  else
  {
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
      $return_array['success'] = '0';
      $return_array['email_msg'] = 'Enter valid email.';  
    }
  }

  if($name == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['name_msg'] = 'Name is required';
  }
  else
  {
     $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $name)) {
      $return_array['success'] = '0';
     $return_array['name_msg'] = 'Enter valid Name.';
    }
  }

  if($phone == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['phone_msg'] = 'Phone is required';
  }
  else
  {
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
     if (!preg_match($string_exp, $phone)) {
       $return_array['success'] = '0';
     $return_array['phone_msg'] = 'Enter valid Phone.';
    }
  }

  if($subject == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['subject_msg'] = 'Subject is required';
  }

  if($message == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['message_msg'] = 'Message is required';
  }
  else
  {
    if (strlen($message) < 2) {
      $return_array['success'] = '0';
      $return_array['message_msg'] = 'Enter valid Message.';
    }
  }  

  return $return_array;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$return_array = validate($name,$email,$phone,$message,$subject);
if($return_array['success'] == '1')
{
  send_email($fname,$email,$phone,$subject,$message);
}

header('Content-type: text/json');
echo json_encode($return_array);
die();

?>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div#output').hide();
    //bind send message here
    $('#send-message').click(sendMessage);
    $('button.close').live('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().find('p').html('');
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
});

/* Contact Form */
function checkEmail(email) {
    var check = /^[\w\.\+-]{1,}\@([\da-zA-Z-]{1,}\.){1,}[\da-zA-Z-]{2,6}$/;
    if (!check.test(email)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function sendMessage() {

    // receive the provided data
    var name = $("input#name").val();
    var email = $("input#email").val();
    var subject = $("input#subject").val();
    var phone = $("input#phone").val();
    var message = $("textarea#message").val();

    message = 'message';
    // check if all the fields are filled
    if (name == '' || phone == '' || email == '' || subject == '' || message == '') {
        $("div#output").show().html('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert-close">x</button><p class="alert-close">You must enter all the fields!</p>');

        return false;
    }

    // verify the email address
    if (!checkEmail(email)) {
        $("div#output").show().html('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button><p>Please enter a valid Email Address</p>');
        return false;
    }

    // make the AJAX request
    var dataString = $('#cform').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'contact.php',
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success == 0) {
                var errors = '<ul><li>';
                if (data.name_msg != '')
                    errors += data.name_msg + '</li>';
                if (data.email_msg != '')
                    errors += '<li>' + data.email_msg + '</li>';
                if (data.phone_msg != '')
                    errors += '<li>' + data.phone_msg + '</li>';
                if (data.message_msg != '')
                    errors += '<li>' + data.message_msg + '</li>';
                if (data.subject_msg != '')
                    errors += '<li>' + data.subject_msg + '</li>';

                $("div#output").removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-error').show().html('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button><p> Could not complete your request. See the errors below!</p>' + errors);
            }
            else if (data.success == 1) {

                $("div#output").removeClass('alert-error').addClass('alert-success').show().html('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button><p>You message has been sent successfully!</p>');
            }

        },
        error: function (error) {
            $("div#output").removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-error').show().html('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button><p> Could not complete your request. See the error below!</p>' + error.statusText);
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that the value of $phone being passed to validate() is correctly retrieved from the request?

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression that validate the name is the same as the one who validate the phone number, quite weird isn't it?

To validate every kind of phone number, you just have check if `$phone` contains only digit with `ctype_digit()`.

Comment: It seems to accept the phone number but now it displays the error message and has the status of 'OK'. So it still isn't successfully sending the message.

Answer (score 0):

How about using

`/^[0-9]+$/` instead of `/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/` at `$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";`?

Or

`if (preg_match($string_exp, $phone)) {` instead of  `if (!preg_match($string_exp, $phone)) {`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex that you use to validate phone numbers:

```
/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/
```

Doesn't accept digits. Given that a phone number typically has digits in it, this regex is most likely invalid in this context.

Comment: The phone number is working now, thanks but it says now that there is an error when I press submit and has the status of 'OK'

Comment: "Could not complete your request. See error the below!" and the error says "OK"

Answer (score 0):

Your regex for validating phone number isn't correct.
Replace the line:

```
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
```

With

```
$string_exp = "/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i";
```

The above regular expression accepts phone numbers in following formats:

```
555-555-5555
5555425555
555 555 5555
1(519) 555-4444
1 (519) 555-4422
1-555-555-5555
1-(555)-555-25555
```